# Media query sass split by resolution

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to strip down sass styles based on the media query resolution? Here is my sass file.I want to split it by blue300.css and blue480.css?

```
.red {


color: red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .blue {
    color: red;
  }
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .blue {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What does strip down mean?

Comment: so for example, i can compile this sass and get blue.css (all in one file), but when a browser doesn't support media query, we want to manually provide a css file based on resolution. is there a way, i can request import max-width:300 styles and compile that as blue300.css?

Comment: What would be the benefit of splitting your media query styles into individual files?  Every user agent downloads *all* stylesheets, even ones that don't currently match.

Comment: Its for a web portal. So, we planned to create sass for each module. but, when mq not supported or not needed (tablet or mobile doesn't need all the css), we plan to split the css into multiple file and serve the file that is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to implement something similar to Jake Archibald's approach to creating a seperate sass file for IE.

[IE Friendly CSS with Sass](http://jakearchibald.github.io/sass-ie/)

In your comment you mention creating stylesheets for different resolutions that don't support media queries.  I would advise against that and just create one default stylesheet for browsers with no media query support.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an npm module and a grunt plugin, wich separates a css file into media query files automatically. In this case it would create a separate css file for every found media query. [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-css-media-cli) is the cli and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-extract-css-media) is the grunt plugin